# Flutter - How to play Instagram videos in your flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-video-player

So I created a video player in my flutter app just like Instagram reels using the video_player: ^2.4.5 package. Everything's fine but I don't want to store all the reels in my firebase storage because it can cost me a lot. So is there a way to just copy paste the link from an Instagram reel and play it in my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add Instagram dev key to use play video and user details check this

`instagram_public_api: ^0.2.3`

[more details](https://pub.dev/packages/instagram_public_api)

Comment: Thank you for this, but can you explain a little more. Please!

Comment: Hi, from this you will get instagram post details including video url so using that you can easily download the videos.